# CSS nth-child every 3 items

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a little issue. I want to style every 3 items. It is hard to explain so i want to explain it with image.

[This is what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlqQV.png)

As you can see, i want to set background as a red every 3 items. We can look this like:

red    red    red 
white  white  white 
red    red    red 
white  white  red

How can i do this using CSS? I don't want to add extra classes for this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Only i have classic parent-item html codes. I want to style items, i've tried 3n+1, 3n+3 and stuff like this, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS Grid to layout the boxes and `<An+B>` notation for selecting every other row of 3 boxes.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  gap: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(6n),
.box:nth-child(6n - 1),
.box:nth-child(6n - 2) {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the elements using JS .

```js
let elementsArray=document.getElementsByClassName("coloredDiv");
let i=3;
while(i<=elementsArray.length){

elementsArray[i].style.backgroundColor="blue"
if(i%3===2)
i=i+4;
else
i++
}
```

```css
.container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:colomn;
width:100px;
height:100px;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;
}

.coloredDiv{
width:30px;
height:30px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="coloredDiv">

</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">
</div>
<div class="coloredDiv">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified is it TABLE or DIV-TABLE leyout. If it's table You can use even and odd rules to color elements:

Simple HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

And CSS code:

```
td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #FFF;
}
tr:nth-child(even) > td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F00;
}
```